# How to limit delete acces from direct link?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have 2 questions and I need your help.First of all, I have made a delete route for comments, but other users logged can also delete comments from direct link...`link.com/deleteComment/id`. How to make this available only for owner of the comment?The owner id is saved in database and can be accessed with `{{ $comment->user_id }}`.

Second problem...In my view, when I click on a photo which have no comments, I'm receiving `undefined variable comment`, but I dont know why because on photos with comments, I have no problem with that.Can I make something like `if comments != empty, dont show it` or something like that?

**CommentsController:**

```
 public function store(Request $request, $post_id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, array(

            'comment' => 'required|min:5|max:2000',
        ));


        $post = Post::find($post_id);

        $comment = new Comment();
        $comment->username = Auth::user()->username;
        $comment->email = Auth::user()->email;
        $comment->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $comment->comment = $request->comment;
        $comment->approved = true;
        $comment->post()->associate($post);

        $comment->save();
        Session::flash('message', "Message posted successfully!");
        return Redirect::back();
    }
```

**PostsController:**

```
    public function delete($id){

        DB::table('posts')->where('id',$id)->delete();

        return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
    }
```

**My view**

```
@foreach($post->comments as $comment)

          <div class="comment d-flex ">

            <p><strong><a class="text-dark" href="/profile/{{ $comment->user_id }}">{{ $comment->username}}</a>: </strong> {{ $comment->comment}}</p>
       @can('update', $post->user->profile)
    <div class="dropdown col-md-6">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-sm" style="background-color: #ffffff00;border: 1px solid #555;color: black;padding: 0 5px" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Select
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit comment</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" title="Options" style="text-decoration: none;" href="/deleteComment/{{$comment->id}}">Delete comment</a>
    </div>
  </div>

          </div>
@endcan
          @endforeach
```

**My route**

```
Route::post('comments/{post_id}', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@store', 'as' => 'comments.store']);

Route::get('/deleteComment/{id}', 'CommentsController@delete');
```

Comment: How to make this available only for the owner of the comment? use laravel policy, https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#creating-policies

Comment: For the second issue, wrap your foreach with  `@if($post->comments->count() > 0) ` 
and `@endif`

Comment: thank you, but this `@if` doesn't work, any solution?

Comment: Did you put the `@if` before the `@foreach` if yes, I think the issue is in `$comment->comment` this line, use `{{ isset($comment->comment) ? $comment->comment : "--" }}`

Comment: yes...maybe I put it wrong? Can you have a look please? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BgeXPV

Comment: Still, you are having the same error? `dd($post->comments)` to see what its showing. or post the error in a image,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to restrict the deletion only for the authenticated user who owns the comment:

```
/**
 *  Comments Controller Method Delete
 */
public function delete($id){

    if(!DB::table('comments')->where('id',$id)->where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->delete()){
        Session::flash('remove', "You do not have permission to delete the comment!");
    }else{
        Session::flash('remove', "Message removed successfully!");
    }

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

For your second question, I think that what happens is that by not having comments you are using the variable without results.

You can try to enclose the statement where you use the variable $comments using this.

For Controller or others files php

```
if (!$comment->isEmpty()) { 
//your code 
}
if ($comment->count()) { 
//your code 
}
if (count($comment)) { 
//your code 
}
```

For Blade

```
@if(!$comment->isEmpty()) 
//your code 
@endif
@if($comment->count()) 
//your code 
@endif
@if(count($comment)) 
//your code
@endif
```

I hope I could help you, if not, please attach more code where they appear exactly what he says, since comments and delete the picture, since I have not seen in the code you have attached. Thanks and good luck.

**References**

[$comment->isEmpty](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_isEmpty)

[$comment->count() and count($comment)](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_count)

**Updated**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @if(!$post->comments->isEmpty()) //****Added
            @if($post->comments->count() > 0)
                @foreach($post->comments as $comment)

                    <div class="comment d-flex ">

                        <p><strong><a class="text-dark"
                                      href="/profile/{{ $comment->user_id }}">{{ $comment->username}}</a>:
                            </strong> {{ isset($comment->comment) ? $comment->comment : "--" }}</p>
                        @can('update', $post->user->profile)

                            <div class="dropdown col-md-6">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-sm"
                                        style="background-color: #ffffff00;border: 1px solid #555;color: black;padding: 0 5px"
                                        data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    Select
                                </button>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit comment</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" title="Options" style="text-decoration: none;"
                                       href="/deleteComment/{{$comment->id}}">Delete comment</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                    @endcan

                @endforeach
            @endif
        @endif //****Added
    </div>
</div>
```

**Updated for delete if admin or no**

```
/**
 *  Comments Controller Method Delete
 */
public function delete($id)
{
    $comment = DB::table('comments')->where('id', $id):

    if(!auth()->user()->admin){
        $comment->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
    }

    if (!$comment->delete()) {
        Session::flash('remove', "You do not have permission to delete the comment!");
    } else {
        Session::flash('remove', "Message removed successfully!");
    }

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

Comment: @AndreiNagy please, Replace here (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VJJZjQ) the delete function by which I modified in my answer.

Comment: You are right, now delete function doesn't work from link :) I'm going to solve the second problem...with $comment undefined variable.Here I don't get it ...how to use that if's?Where and how should I post that?

Comment: @AndreiNagy, please can you return to send the codepen of view where the error occurs with the picture?

Comment: here is my code : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMMgdm, here is photo of error: https://imgur.com/a/KhgTITG . Something weird is that, in the index, where I have same photos, I click on the photo without comments without any error, but...from my profile I can't. Should I add my function in index of my profile?Because, from profile, I press on photo, which is the `show.blade.php`

Comment: @AndreiNagy, you must enclose the block where the problem occurs with one of these conditions (the one that best suits your code).

It can also enclose only the variable that gives the problem, although that can break the logic showing incomplete data for missing the data.                                 Please accept it as the correct answer, if it has been helpful. Thank you.

Comment: here is also my index of profile...if that s matter : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GbbRRV

Comment: @AndreiNagy, thanks, for the code, but it is not there the variable that gives you the problem, please, I just need the code of the view where the problem gives you to create a code that can help you solve the problem.

Comment: Can you `dd($comment)` inside the foreach and send the image of the dd

Comment: Doesn't work `dd($comment)` inside the foreach... `  @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
           dd($comment)`

Comment: Inside the foreach do `@if(isset($comment))` and `@endif` and wrap your view

Comment: for NewWorld, this is what you are looking for? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OeeJWM

Comment: @AndreiNagy, I have updated your code please review it.
Instead of use dd($post->comments) use var_dump($post->comments). Por favor, acéptelo como la respuesta correcta, si ha sido útil. Gracias.

Comment: Guys, I think here isn't the problem...Because I just deleted my code with `$comment` and I have same problem, I think is in another place...

Comment: @AndreiNagy, please can you return to send the codepen of view where the error occurs with the picture?

Comment: So. If i click from my feed index(index from posts), I can see the post without any comment, and click it, with same link.But, when I click from index(index from profile), I get this error: https://imgur.com/a/Exlzeeq. Here is my index profile code : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KjjKZX

Comment: Maybe you want to share with you other code? I'm so confused with this...

Comment: I solved the problem :) it was a modal with this variable.

Comment: Sir, can you help me with first problem?Because now, even if I am creator of the post, I can't delete comments of other users, how to fix that?Can I be able to delete comments of other users and my comments from another posts?

Comment: @AndreiNagy, do you use a role system? while i will think and i will give you an example code and update it in my answer.

Comment: @AndreyNagy, or better raised, how do you verify that a user is an administrator? I give you an example telling you that you have a boolean admin field in the user table with which you verify that you are an administrator. Check the example in my answer. Thanks and kind regards.

Comment: If you want to comment more on the subject, we could do a chat, since stackoverflow prefers to avoid the prolonged discussions on the subject in the comments. Thank you. https://chat.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

The first question can be done easily. In your `destroy()` function, just check comment owner:

```
// Check comment owner    
if($comment->user_id != \Auth::id()){
   return abort(401);
}

// Do logic code to delete comment.
```

The second question, you can check exist comment like this :

```
if(! $comments->isEmpty()) {
  // Do logic code to show comment
}
```

Comment: At first function, I receive `Undefined variable: comment`

Comment: You should get the `$comment` variable first, something like this : `$comment = Comment::findOrFail($comment_id)`;